# How to calculate the most abundant pixel value in a layer stack of different classifications of the same area (majority vote)?

Tags: r, spatial, raster, r-raster

I have multiple classifications as rasters, each of one different group, that have discrete integer pixel values that represent certain classes (e.g.: 111 for stable coniferous forest). I want to find out which value is per pixel the most abundant in all of the classifications, which i stacked into a raster stack.

Is there a function for that? If not any Ideas how solve this task?

```r
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(nrows = 4, ncols = 4, xmn = 0)
r1[] <- sample(1:4, 16, replace = T)

r2 <- raster(nrows = 4, ncols = 4, xmn = 0)
r2[] <- sample(1:4, 16, replace = T)

r3 <- raster(nrows = 4, ncols = 4, xmn = 0)
r3[] <- sample(1:4, 16, replace = T)

r <- stack(r1, r2 ,r3)
r[2,2]
```

For example is class 1,2,3 or 4 most abundant in Pixel [2,2]?
In the ende i would like to have one raster layer with the most abundat pixel value and one with the fraction this value had (staying in the above example, values 1, 1 and 4, so value 1 would "win" with a rate of 66%).

Answer (score 1):

If you use random values for your example, you should fix the random seed to make it reproducible, just FYI.

This should do what you need:

```
library(raster)

set.seed(42)

r1 <- raster(nrows = 4, ncols = 4, xmn = 0)
r1[] <- sample(1:4, 16, replace = T)

r2 <- raster(nrows = 4, ncols = 4, xmn = 0)
r2[] <- sample(1:4, 16, replace = T)

r3 <- raster(nrows = 4, ncols = 4, xmn = 0)
r3[] <- sample(1:4, 16, replace = T)

r <- stack(r1, r2 ,r3)

f <- function(x){

  n <- length(x)

  if (length(unique(x)) == n){

    return(c(NA,NA))

  }else{

    v <- as.integer(names(which.max(table(x))))

    p <- (sum(x == v) / n) * 100

    return(c(v,p))

  }
}
```

We create a function that takes a vector as input, calculates the majority value and returns is along with the percentage it has on the length of the vector. The function is then passed to `calc` to be applied to the stack `r`. So what you'll get is a 2-band raster.

If there's no repeated value, so if the length of unique values is equal to the length of the vector, `NA` will be returned.

Not sure what happens when you have two classes that have the same majority value, probably the function just takes one of them You could also add a check for that.

So if we now look at the pixel `[2,2]`, we can check out the results:

The value is `1`, and the fraction is `66%` (like the others)

```
> r[2,2]
     layer.1 layer.2 layer.3
[1,]       3       1       1

plot(calc(x = r, fun = f2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `raster::modal` method. It has an argument `ties` that you may want to consider.

```
library(raster)
set.seed(42)
r <- raster(nrows = 4, ncols = 4, xmn = 0)
s <- stack(lapply(1:12, function(i) setValues(r, sample(1:4, 16, replace = TRUE))))

x <- modal(s)
plot(x)
```